# CONCATENATE a CASE in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, case

I need to run a `CASE` expression on a number of columns, the columns are Boolean, so if it's 0 I need to populate the column with the column name and if it's 1, I ignore the column/value. I then need to concatenate all these columns into one. Is it possible to do this in Oracle SQL?

I've tried this:

```
Select
    ||CASE
       WHEN COL_A = 0 THEN 'COL_A'
       ELSE ''
    END||','
    ||CASE
       WHEN COL_B = 0 THEN 'COL_B'
       ELSE ''
    END||
from ABC.123
```

Can this even been done? If not this way are there any other ways?

Comment: Does the above give you an error? Seems valid in concept, but I don't know much about oracle, only need the `||` between the `CASE` statements I'd think.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will work (if you clean up the syntax). Here's a simple example:

```
with q as (
select 0 col_a, 1 col_b, 'Rec 1' id from dual
union all
select 1, 0, 'Rec 2' from dual
union all
select 0, 0, 'Rec 3' from dual
)
Select id, 
    CASE
       WHEN COL_A = 0 THEN 'COL_A'
       ELSE ''
    END||','
    ||CASE
       WHEN COL_B = 0 THEN 'COL_B'
       ELSE ''
    END "TheString"
from q
```

Result:

```
ID      TheString
------- -------------------   
Rec 1   COL_A,
Rec 2   ,COL_B
Rec 3   COL_A,COL_B
```